# How to add sublist to Note application with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS. I have a task - to do an app like Notes. User can add sublist to his notes, and note have to save to the state in subarray. I need to save sublist in the array inside object. I need to get state like this:
`[...notes, { _id: noteId, text: noteText, notes: [{_id: subNoteId, text: subNoteText, notes[]}] }]`.

How can I to do this?

Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lamarr-u5hug?file=/src/App.js

Thank you for any help, and sorry for my English

```
const NoteForm = ({ saveNote, placeholder }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    saveNote(value);
    setValue("");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
        value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const NoteList = ({ notes, saveNote }) => {

  const renderSubNotes = (noteArr) => {

    const list = noteArr.map((note) => {
      let subNote;
      if (note.notes && note.notes.length > 0) {
        subNote = renderSubNotes(note.notes);
      }
      return (
        <div key={note._id}>
          <li>{note.text}</li>
          <NoteForm placeholder="Enter your sub note" saveNote={saveNote} />
          {subNote}
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <ul>{list}</ul>;
  };

  return renderSubNotes(notes);
};

export default function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  const saveHandler = (text) => {
    const trimmedText = text.trim();
    const noteId =
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + trimmedText.replace(/\s/g, "");
    if (trimmedText.length > 0) {
      setNotes([...notes, { _id: noteId, text: trimmedText, notes: [] }]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes</h1>
      <NoteList notes={notes} saveNote={saveHandler} />
      <NoteForm
        saveNote={saveHandler}
        placeholder="Enter your note"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In this case you're performing dynamic rendering based on a stateful variable. It looks like your stateful variable notes is an array of objects, which is good. This is what I would suggest, based on what it looks like you're trying to do. So what exactly is not working? This code looks like it should work.

Comment: @TheFunk I don't know how I can save sub note in the array  inside object

Comment: check my answer below and see if that sheds some light on an easy way to update your notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your saveHandler function is where you're saving your array of notes.

Specifically, this line:

```
      setNotes([...notes, { _id: noteId, text: trimmedText, notes: [] }]);
```

But at the moment you're saving an empty array. What if you create another stateful variable called currentNote or something like that, relative to whatever note the user is currently working on within the application? While they are working on that note, the stateful currentNote object is updated with the relevant data, e.g. noteID, content, and parentID. Then, when the user has finished editing that particular note, by either pressing save or the plus button to add a new subnote, etc, that should fire a function such as your saveHandler to add the currentNote object to the "notes" array in the stateful "notes" variable. I'm not sure I like that the stateful variable notes contains an array within it called notes as well. I think this may cause confusion.

But in short, your setNotes line could change to something like (bear with me my JS syntax skills suck):

```
let newNotes= [...notes.notes];
newNotes.push(currentNote);
setNotes([...notes, { _id: noteId, text: trimmedText, notes: newNotes }]);
```

Wherein your stateful currentNote object is copied into the notes array on every save.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it

Comment: No problem. If you need further guidance feel free to edit your post with updated code, I will be around.

Comment: Did this help with your issue @Evgesha?